# Expose certain bash script commands to other users

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have a bash script named `/root/scripts/start-apache` containing:

```
systemctl start apache2
sendTelegramNotice "Apache started from the web"
echo Done
```

And `/root/scripts/stop-apache`:

```
systemctl stop apache2
sendTelegramNotice "Apache stopped from the web"
echo Done
```

In visudo I added:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /root/scripts/start-apache
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /root/scripts/stop-apache
```

And I added the commands to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ln -s /root/scripts/{start-apache,stop-apache} /usr/local/bin/
```

Now, when I am logged in as user `www-data`, I can run the commands like this:

```
sudo start-apache
sudo stop-apache
```

Is this a safe way to do this? Is my assumption correct, that when I correctly validate the input on my bash script commands, security wise this is safe for production? If not, then what would be the best practice to achieve this?

I want to create simple commands like `banip 0.0.0.0` `unbanip 0.0.0.0` `slowtrafficdown` and expose them to `www-data`, but I don't want to give `www-data` the elevated privileges to run the underlying commands (like iptables/ipset etc) directly.

Comment: What do you mean when you ask "is this a safe way to do this?" What is "safe"?

Comment: With safe I mean I dont want to unintentionally create any vulnerabilities. For example if a hacker would gain acces to the user `www-data` could he use `start-apache` or `stop-apache` to further escalate privileges or not?

Comment: Besides following best practices guides, and doing your research and understanding the system and possible attack services, there's not much else to do.